# CRichEditCtrl::StreamIn doesn't read the whole text file

Tags: c++, mfc, cricheditctrl

I have a text file that I would like to read and then put it in a rich edit box. The problem is, the `pbBuff` buffer gets the whole file, but then only the first line is added to the CRichEditCtrl widget.

Here is the callback function:

```
static DWORD CALLBACK StreamInCallback(DWORD dwCookie, LPBYTE pbBuff, LONG cb, LONG FAR *pcb) 
{   
    CFile* dat = (CFile*) dwCookie;
    *pcb = dat->Read(pbBuff, cb);

    return 0; 
}
```

And how I set it in the `OnInitDialog()` function:

```
CFile dat(_T("readme.txt"), CFile::modeRead);
EDITSTREAM es;
es.dwCookie = (DWORD)&dat; 
es.pfnCallback = StreamInCallback;  
m_RichEditBesedilo.StreamIn(SF_TEXT, es);
```

Comment: If debugging shows that pbBuff is getting filled with the entire file, StreamIn is working and your problem lies elsewhere.  Make sure that your CRichEditCtrl is properly displaying multi-line text when the text is inserted by other means. If not, it could be because of flags controlling the RichEdit or missing initializations required for RichEdit to function.

Comment: You haven't created the control with the ES_MULTILINE style set - by default rich edit controls only show a single line without this.

Comment: Thanks, that resolved it. You can put that as an answer and I'll accept it.